# Show/hide shipping methods on checkout page depending on current store

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping-methods, stores

Is there any way to decide shipping methods on the checkout page depending on current store?

For example:
 If **storeview A** then show only Freeshipping. If **storeview B** then show only Flatrate.

I am using IWD onepage checkout extension.

In System > configuration > shipping methods :

I have set No to Enabled for My 2nd Website but, That method is still displying on Checkout page.

[image]

Current settings are as follow:

Default Config : Flatrate > Enabled : No 
Website One : Flatrate > Enabled : Yes [Default checkbox is not selected] 
Website Two : Flatrate > Enabled : NO [Default checkbox is selected]

Answer (score 1):

You can enable/disable shipping methods in magento admin panel based on the store view. so that the enabled shipping method only be visible for that particular store view.

> System >  Configuration > Shipping Method

Choose the store scope in top left drop down of the system configuration

Comment: I have made edit in my question kindly check it.

Comment: check in store view also some time the default config check-box may unticked

Comment: I have specified my settings in the question now.

Comment: Flush the cache and check

Comment: All cache is cleared.

Comment: can you share the frontend url or both store?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39385/discussion-between-manikandan-and-vedu).

Answer (score 0):

Go to `System > Configuration > Shipping Methods`

You can switch STOREs and can set Shipping Methods to `Enable -> Yes OR No.`
[image]

Comment: I have made edit in my question kindly check it.

Comment: clear CACHE and flush checkout session at frontend

Comment: All cache and index is cleared.

Comment: I mean clear CART and add product again to check

Comment: does this worked ?

Comment: Thank you for your help but It did not worked.